# TeX Live 2021 CJK bug

Tags: texlive, cjk, macos

Including CJK seems to disable the effects of \bf and \it.
For instance, the picture
[image]
is generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
One \bf{two} \it{three}.
\end{document}
```

I am using macOS Big Sur 11.4 + TeX Live 2021 (with all packages updated to the latest versions via TeX Live Utility 1.49.)
Commenting off the second line gets the following normal picture. [image]

Comment: Thanks David. But the problem remains even if I use your suggested commands: \textbf{two} \itshape{three}.

Comment: Yes I deleted my answer, your code though produces bold italic not normal italic due to the wrong code. There were some changes to internal font handling at the last release, I'll check if this effect with cjk package is known.

Comment: I appreciate that!!

Comment: I've raised it with the latex project team

Comment: Your example should now work if you update texlive.

Comment: @David, Indeed!! Thanks again!!

Comment: Independent of the fact that firstaid was by mistake not uploaded, one minor comment on your example: \bf and \it are commands that have been deprecated around 1994 and do in fact not always work (not all classes contain compatibility definitions for it). The correct LaTeX commands are \textbf{...} and \textit{....}.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `firstaid` fix for this is now in texlive 2021, so the example now works with pdflatex as well as pdflatex-dev.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
One \textbf{two} \textit{three}.
\end{document}
```

there is a known incompatibility with CJK.sty with recent LaTeX releases. The `first-aid` mechanism contains a fix for this but currently in the development branch so this document works as intended with `pdflatex-dev` rather than `pdflatex`.

<strike>It will work with `pdflatex` after the  first-aid is updated in the main branch.</strike>